maximum data size sent by SDO
I have a question about the SDO function.
From what I understand, we can only send messages of 8 bytes and in the case of an SDO where the data exceeds these 8 bytes, it will be stored in an array/record. My question is as follows: given that we can only store data of 8 bytes maximum in the OD per data, this means that our SDO will only be able to send 8 bytes by 8 bytes and that we'll have to initialize it with each new piece of data (with an SDO request), so there's nothing to be gained by using segmentation since it doesn't segment anything? moreover, with the Data-ack format, this will create a lot of overhead (with each frame sent, an ack frame will be sent)?
i've created a small simulation based on the lely canopen library, and i can't send an SDO of more than 8 bytes. so i'm wondering what segmentation is for?

You could buffer the received bytes at the receiving end, thus making segmentation of a larger message into smaller packets work as if one larger message was sent (given some extra transmission time and a little overhead).

Have you actually read up on the 3 different forms of the SDO protocol? Are you asking why the segmented transfer exists and why expedited or block transfers aren't always used?

Yes, I've looked into the different types of SDOs, but I still can't understand how segmented packets work. If the Object Dictionary (OD) can only hold data up to 8 bytes, I don't see the point of segmentation. For example, if I have 1 KB of data to send, I would need to split it into several smaller chunks of 8 bytes each, stored in an array (where each 8-byte segment is a sub-index). I would then have to send a request each time I finish sending the first 8 bytes... which makes me lose a lot of bandwidth.I don’t understand the goal of segmentation if I have to send a new request each time

OD entries are not limited to 8 bytes. The purpose of having subindexes is not storing larger entries. They help logically organizing the OD and they also extend the address space from 16 bits to 24 bits.
Segmented SDOs can transfer up to 4 GiB of data, since the initial SDO package has a 4-byte field to indicate the size of the transfer. The following SDO segment packages can carry up to 7 bytes of data.
I think this 4 GiB segmented SDO transfer size limit also limits the size of OD entries in practice.
Also see my somewhat related answer on topic of block transfers.
